# Can I get the static resources components name in apex?

Tags: apex, static-resources, zip

I have one requirement where I want the components present in the static resources.
I have uploaded the zip files having three images.

Now I want to get the names of that three images in apex however, I am getting the zip folder name but can't get the images in the apex.

Is there anything that I can do, do let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex) and use that to read the list of files available in the ZIP resource file. Specific instructions are available in the README file. Here's the source code example directly from the documentation:

```
Attachment sampleAttachment = [SELECT Name, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id='<ID_OF_ATTACHMENT>'];
Zippex sampleZip = new Zippex(sampleAttachment.Body);
Set <String> fileNames = sampleZip.getFileNames();
for (String fileName : fileNames)
{
    System.debug('file: ' + fileName);
}
```